# Kendo UI Wont work when I Enable an Event - C#, ASP.NET, MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-treeview

I'm trying to add a .Select() event to my Kendo Treeview. But when I run the Program, all my Kendo Controls wont work. But when I place the Event in Comments, then they work again.

My CSHTML Kendo Treeview look like this:

```
        @(Html.Kendo().TreeView()
        .Name("treeViewDatabase")
        .DataTextField("Name")
        .DataSource(dataScource => dataScource
            .Model(m => m
                .Id("ID")
                .HasChildren("HasChildren")
            )
            .Read(read => read.Action("RetrieveDataTable", "Management", new { id = Model.ID, type = Model.Type }))
        )
        .Events(events => events
            .Select("onSelect"))
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "color:white;" })
)
```

and the problem lies with the Event function,
but can someone please tell me what's wrong?

Thanks in Advance,

Comment: Have you added a Jquery function event called `onSelect` in your code??

Comment: yes, but it doesnt matter if that part works or not. because I tried several funnctions and even comments but aslong the event is not in comments, my kendo controls wont work

Comment: If the Jquery breaks then all related kendo stuff's will break, Because all are converted into jquery if you inspect the DOm you will find out.  Open your browser console and see what error you get

Comment: Never mind. found the problem

Comment: Thank you all for helping me. I made a mistake in my onSelect part

Comment: thats it,, So just remember to use console window for errors, and if jquery breaks then kendo will break too, As its jquery only...